# Lookup Twitter Spaces created by accounts I follow

Tags: twitter, audio-streaming, twitter-api-v2

According to [this page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/spaces/lookup/introduction),

> you can lookup Spaces created by accounts followed by a specific user. Given a single user ID, a dedicated endpoint will traverse the user’s followings and return live or upcoming Spaces created by any of these users.

I would like to check periodically for Spaces scheduled by any of the ~10k accounts I follow, but I can't find the "dedicated endpoint."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is an error in the Twitter developer documentation - this functionality does not exist in the API. You'd need to build this via a much more manual process of calling the [lookup endpoint by creator ID](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/spaces/lookup/api-reference/get-spaces-by-creator-ids) - the endpoint can support up to 100 user IDs at a time, so that will take some time to cover your larger number of accounts followed.

(side note, I've asked for the documentation to be updated to correct this confusing statement)

Comment: Well, that's the answer I guess. I can live with that, thanks Andy.

Comment: Possibly another doc error: `subscriber_count` is not marked as available only to the space owner. I get a 403 when attempting to retrieve it. see: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/data-dictionary/object-model/space